# Cannot resolve symbol myLatitude

Tags: java, android

new to programming i know i'm doing something that's probably really obviously wrong to do with passing or using the wrong variables but i just can't work out what.

Here is my code:

```
public class CameraViewActivity extends Activity implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnLocationChangedListener, OnAzimuthChangedListener {


private double mAzimuthReal = 0;
private double mAzimuthTheoretical = 0;
private static double AZIMUTH_ACCURACY = 5;
private double mMyLatitude = 0;
private double mMyLongitude = 0;




private List<Double> calculateAzimuthAccuracy(double azimuth) {
    double minAngle = azimuth - AZIMUTH_ACCURACY;
    double maxAngle = azimuth + AZIMUTH_ACCURACY;
    List<Double> minMax = new ArrayList<Double>();


@Override
public void onAzimuthChanged(float azimuthChangedFrom, float azimuthChangedTo) {
    mAzimuthReal = azimuthChangedTo;
    mAzimuthTheoretical = calculateTheoreticalAzimuth();

    pointerIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);


    double minAngle = calculateAzimuthAccuracy(mAzimuthTheoretical).get(0);
    double maxAngle = calculateAzimuthAccuracy(mAzimuthTheoretical).get(1);




    if (isBetween(minAngle, maxAngle, mAzimuthReaal) {

        pointerIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    else {
        pointerIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

    updateDescription();
}
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [re-take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your fields aren't being referenced in `onAzimuthChanged`... Also don't capitalize your variables, please

Comment: In which lines they come unresolved? You are using them pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel At the bottom

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you will change them / keep that in mind in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
isRange(mMyLatitude, mMyLongitude, mPoi.getPoiLatitude(), mPoi.getPoiLongitude)
```

instead of

```
isRange(MyLatitude, MyLongitude, MpoiLatitude, MpoiLongitude)
```

**FYI,** its better to use small letter for naming variable.

Comment: Thank you ! and i will definitely fix that :D

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

In this function you need to pass as paramters either two locations and use their coordinates in the function inRange or you pass four coordinates and use them.

```
public void onAzimuthChanged(float azimuthChangedFrom, float azimuthChangedTo) {
mAzimuthReal = azimuthChangedTo;
mAzimuthTheoretical = calculateTheoreticalAzimuth();

pointerIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);


double minAngle = calculateAzimuthAccuracy(mAzimuthTheoretical).get(0);
double maxAngle = calculateAzimuthAccuracy(mAzimuthTheoretical).get(1);




if (isBetween(minAngle, maxAngle, mAzimuthReal) && isRange(MyLatitude, MyLongitude, MpoiLatitude, MpoiLongitude)) {

    pointerIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
else {
    pointerIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

updateDescription();
}
```

This has no meaning

```
isRange(MyLatitude, MyLongitude, MpoiLatitude, MpoiLongitude);
```

One more thing, adapt a professional naming criteria. Giving your attributes names that start with capital letters is quite MEH.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i tried it but they're still unresolved :(